# How to hide a label for specific text field input?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I´ve created a Xcode project with just one button, one text field and one label. I want to make the label only visible, when the text field input is "test123" or the button gets pressed. The part with the button works well, but no matter what i type in the textfield, the label stays hidden. Anyone help? This is my current code:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Examplefield: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {

               super.viewDidLoad()
               // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

               Label.hidden = true

        Examplefield.resignFirstResponder()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func ButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

        Label.hidden = false
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        if Examplefield.text == "test123" {
            Label.hidden = false

    }
        else {
            Label.hidden = true
        }

          }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to check the String on the shouldChangeCharactersInRange delegate method instead of the current textFieldDidEndEditing.

Please refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

Comment: Sorry, but still don´t get it. Could you give me an example code for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to connect the “Editing Changed” event of the text field to an action in your view controller:

[image: connecting the editing changed event]

The text field fires the “Editing Changed” event whenever the user changes the contents of the field. You don't have to set the delegate or register for a notification.

There are also “Editing Did End” and “Did End on Exit” events if you want to wait until the user exits the field.

Comment: This is even better, great help!

Comment: Nicely done! Still helpful in year 2021

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the *shouldChangeCharactersInRange* method from the [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/) in order to check if the string is the same when the text changes:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if (string == "test123") {
        self.Label.hidden = false
    } else {
        self.Label.hidden = true
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: The text field still remains hidden when i insert "test123" :(

Answer (score 0):

Using `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` works well, but another option would be using the `textFieldDidChange` NSNotification.

In your `viewDidLoad`, register for the notification:

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("textFieldDidChange:"), name: "UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification", object: nil)
```

Then define the appropriate method:

```
 func textFieldDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.label.hidden = (self.textField.text == "test123")
}
```

Comment: Is there a opportunity to display the message (make the label visible) not until the user ends editing the text field?

Comment: In that case you'll need to make your original approach work, using textFieldDidEndEditing. Trying just using textField.text instead of the actual property name. textField will always be the textfield that is triggering the delegate method call.

Answer (score -1):

Use UITextField Delegate method

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    // your condition
}
```

[image]